# Middle click paste not working in terminal

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, paste

I have upgraded several machines to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and enabled the "middle click paste" in the gnome settings. On one machine the middle click paste does not work in terminal windows but in other applications. Is there another setting that controls clicks in terminal windows?

Comment: Are all the machines same configuration of hardware??

Comment: One other is same hardware but different configuration. Others are similar configurations with different hardware.